# Updating start-stop-daemon on Debian

Tags: debian, start-stop-daemon

I have Debian Lenny box, where I plan to extensively use `start-stop-daemon`. The trouble is, the standard Debian `start-stop-daemon` doesn't support output redirection: `--stdout` and `--stderr` keys, which I want to use to log daemons activity.

Should I just update `start-stop-daemon` from sources? I tried `apt-get` update process, the version still lacks features. Will it break something in Debian? Or should I compile new `start-stop-daemon` to some new directory and use it for my daemons, leaving standard Debian package in place?

I don't want to write `.sh` wrapper scripts to each daemon, as there will be many of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I'd suggest backporting the version you want to lenny from unstable.; just grab all the sources from the unstable tree for that package... but, oof, it's in the dpkg package, which is probably more than you want to bite off.

So yes, compile it yourself and put it in /usr/local/bin/ and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

[The man-page](http://man.cx/start-stop-daemon%288%29) for start-stop-deamon does provide a clue on how to redirect stdout/stderr, albeit in a cryptic fashion:

> Any arguments  given after -- on the command line are passed unmodified to the program being started.

Thus, the following syntax would allow you to use start-stop-daemon with redirection of stdout/stderr

```
    OPTIONS=" 1>/dev/null 2>${logfile}"
    start-stop-daemon --start --startas /usr/bin/foo  -- $OPTIONS
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you think to write a .sh wrapper for start-stop-deamon instead?

You could rename original start-stop-deamon executable and create your .sh wrapper with "start-stop-deamon" name.

Comment: Hmmm... I don't know what to write there. Is there a way to redirect a daemon's output in `start-stop-daemon` without using `--stdout`/`--stderr` (maybe with `&1>`, `&2>`) ?

Comment: Yes...I think something like &1> &2>.